# How to create loop to scrape data from a column from a wikipedia table?

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm currently stuck on a loop in an attempt to scrape data from the `Symbols` from a single Wikipedia [List of S&P 500 companies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) using BeautifulSoup on Python 2.7. Here is the work in progress of my code:

```
#import the necessary libraries & modules
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#link to be scraped assigned to a variable
wiki_page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

#A function that gets the URL of the page to be scraped
#,gets the html content and uses BeautifulSoup to parse html content

def make_soup(link):
    get_page = requests.get(link)
    html = get_page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return  soup

soup = make_soup(wiki_page)

#Variable (tickers) which will store the
tickers = ['']

#Need help in creating a loop that will append the 'tickers' variable with data from the 'Symbols' column
```

My desired output is for `tickers` variable to be populated by the data from the `Symbols` column such that `tickers = ['MM', 'AAPL'...........]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})  # find the table
tickers = []
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:  # iterate over the rows, starting from 
                                      # the second (first one is the header row)
    symbol_cell = row.find_all('td')[0]  #  the Symbol col is the first <td> in every row 
    tickers.append(symbol_cell.text)

print(tickers)
# ['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ATVI', 'AYI', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AAP', 'AES', 'AET', 'AMG', 'AFL', 'A', 'APD', 'AKAM', 'ALK', 'ALB', 'ARE', 'ALXN', 'ALGN', 'ALLE', 'AGN', 'ADS', 'LNT', 'ALL', 'GOOGL', 'GOOG', 'MO', 'AMZN', 'AEE', 'AAL', 'AEP', 'AXP', 'AIG', 'AMT', 'AWK', 'AMP', 'ABC', 'AME', 'AMGN', 'APH', 'APC', 'ADI', 'ANSS', 'ANTM', 'AON', 'APA', 'AIV', 'AAPL', 'AMAT', 'ADM', 'ARNC', 'AJG', 'AIZ', 'T', 'ADSK', 'ADP', 'AN', 'AZO', 'AVB', 'AVY', 'BHGE', 'BLL', 'BAC', 'BK', 'BCR', 'BAX', 'BBT', 'BDX', 'BBBY', 'BRK.B', 'BBY', 'BIIB', 'BLK', 'HRB', 'BA', 'BWA', 'BXP', 'BSX', 'BMY', 'AVGO', 'BF.B', 'CHRW', 'CA', 'COG', 'CPB', 'COF', 'CAH', 'CBOE', 'KMX', 'CCL', 'CAT', 'CBG', 'CBS', 'CELG', 'CNC', 'CNP', 'CTL', 'CERN', 'CF', 'SCHW', 'CHTR', 'CHK', 'CVX', 'CMG', 'CB', 'CHD', 'CI', 'XEC', 'CINF', 'CTAS', 'CSCO', 'C', 'CFG', 'CTXS', 'CLX', 'CME', 'CMS', 'COH', 'KO', 'CTSH', 'CL', 'CMCSA', 'CMA', 'CAG', 'CXO', 'COP', 'ED', 'STZ', 'COO', 'GLW', 'COST', 'COTY', 'CCI', 'CSRA', 'CSX', 'CMI', 'CVS', 'DHI', 'DHR', 'DRI', 'DVA', 'DE', 'DLPH', 'DAL', 'XRAY', 'DVN', 'DLR', 'DFS', 'DISCA', 'DISCK', 'DISH', 'DG', 'DLTR', 'D', 'DOV', 'DOW', 'DPS', 'DTE', 'DD', 'DUK', 'DXC', 'ETFC', 'EMN', 'ETN', 'EBAY', 'ECL', 'EIX', 'EW', 'EA', 'EMR', 'ETR', 'EVHC', 'EOG', 'EQT', 'EFX', 'EQIX', 'EQR', 'ESS', 'EL', 'ES', 'RE', 'EXC', 'EXPE', 'EXPD', 'ESRX', 'EXR', 'XOM', 'FFIV', 'FB', 'FAST', 'FRT', 'FDX', 'FIS', 'FITB', 'FE', 'FISV', 'FLIR', 'FLS', 'FLR', 'FMC', 'FL', 'F', 'FTV', 'FBHS', 'BEN', 'FCX', 'GPS', 'GRMN', 'IT', 'GD', 'GE', 'GGP', 'GIS', 'GM', 'GPC', 'GILD', 'GPN', 'GS', 'GT', 'GWW', 'HAL', 'HBI', 'HOG', 'HRS', 'HIG', 'HAS', 'HCA', 'HCP', 'HP', 'HSIC', 'HSY', 'HES', 'HPE', 'HLT', 'HOLX', 'HD', 'HON', 'HRL', 'HST', 'HPQ', 'HUM', 'HBAN', 'IDXX', 'INFO', 'ITW', 'ILMN', 'IR', 'INTC', 'ICE', 'IBM', 'INCY', 'IP', 'IPG', 'IFF', 'INTU', 'ISRG', 'IVZ', 'IRM', 'JEC', 'JBHT', 'SJM', 'JNJ', 'JCI', 'JPM', 'JNPR', 'KSU', 'K', 'KEY', 'KMB', 'KIM', 'KMI', 'KLAC', 'KSS', 'KHC', 'KR', 'LB', 'LLL', 'LH', 'LRCX', 'LEG', 'LEN', 'LVLT', 'LUK', 'LLY', 'LNC', 'LKQ', 'LMT', 'L', 'LOW', 'LYB', 'MTB', 'MAC', 'M', 'MNK', 'MRO', 'MPC', 'MAR', 'MMC', 'MLM', 'MAS', 'MA', 'MAT', 'MKC', 'MCD', 'MCK', 'MDT', 'MRK', 'MET', 'MTD', 'KORS', 'MCHP', 'MU', 'MSFT', 'MAA', 'MHK', 'TAP', 'MDLZ', 'MON', 'MNST', 'MCO', 'MS', 'MOS', 'MSI', 'MUR', 'MYL', 'NDAQ', 'NOV', 'NAVI', 'NTAP', 'NFLX', 'NWL', 'NFX', 'NEM', 'NWSA', 'NWS', 'NEE', 'NLSN', 'NKE', 'NI', 'NBL', 'JWN', 'NSC', 'NTRS', 'NOC', 'NRG', 'NUE', 'NVDA', 'ORLY', 'OXY', 'OMC', 'OKE', 'ORCL', 'PCAR', 'PH', 'PDCO', 'PAYX', 'PYPL', 'PNR', 'PBCT', 'PEP', 'PKI', 'PRGO', 'PFE', 'PCG', 'PM', 'PSX', 'PNW', 'PXD', 'PNC', 'RL', 'PPG', 'PPL', 'PX', 'PCLN', 'PFG', 'PG', 'PGR', 'PLD', 'PRU', 'PEG', 'PSA', 'PHM', 'PVH', 'QRVO', 'PWR', 'QCOM', 'DGX', 'RRC', 'RJF', 'RTN', 'O', 'RHT', 'REG', 'REGN', 'RF', 'RSG', 'RAI', 'RHI', 'ROK', 'COL', 'ROP', 'ROST', 'RCL', 'CRM', 'SCG', 'SLB', 'SNI', 'STX', 'SEE', 'SRE', 'SHW', 'SIG', 'SPG', 'SWKS', 'SLG', 'SNA', 'SO', 'LUV', 'SPGI', 'SWK', 'SPLS', 'SBUX', 'STT', 'SRCL', 'SYK', 'STI', 'SYMC', 'SYF', 'SNPS', 'SYY', 'TROW', 'TGT', 'TEL', 'FTI', 'TSO', 'TXN', 'TXT', 'TMO', 'TIF', 'TWX', 'TJX', 'TMK', 'TSS', 'TSCO', 'TDG', 'RIG', 'TRV', 'TRIP', 'FOXA', 'FOX', 'TSN', 'UDR', 'ULTA', 'USB', 'UA', 'UAA', 'UNP', 'UAL', 'UNH', 'UPS', 'URI', 'UTX', 'UHS', 'UNM', 'VFC', 'VLO', 'VAR', 'VTR', 'VRSN', 'VRSK', 'VZ', 'VRTX', 'VIAB', 'V', 'VNO', 'VMC', 'WMT', 'WBA', 'DIS', 'WM', 'WAT', 'WEC', 'WFC', 'HCN', 'WDC', 'WU', 'WRK', 'WY', 'WHR', 'WFM', 'WMB', 'WLTW', 'WYN', 'WYNN', 'XEL', 'XRX', 'XLNX', 'XL', 'XYL', 'YUM', 'ZBH', 'ZION', 'ZTS']
```

With list comprehension:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})  # find the table
tickets = [row.find_all('td')[0].text for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]]
```

Comment: Loop working as I wanted however, in the output for each shows a "u" before every ticker. For egs; u'MMM' instead of 'MMM'. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @Mysterio You don't. There is nothing to "resolve". This simply shows these are unicode strings. If you want to "resolve" this, migrate to Python 3, where all strings are unicode.

Comment: Oh Ok. I was limited to Python 2 for my financial module in grad school so I stuck with the version I know. Is migration to Python 3 recommended?

Answer (score 2):

```
#Variable (tickers) which will store the
tickers = []

table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    tickers.append(row.find('a').text)
```